# Spring cloud gateway - request body

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

Is it possible to do a routing based on a parameter from the request body?
Something like

```
if x = 'value' -> route to address1 else to address2?
```

If so, how would this be accomplished?
Any help is more than welcomed.

Comment: Write a custom filter